# How to trigger an event when user click on the item of the list view?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I will like to ask that I will to trigger an event which when the user click on the item in the list view then do the thing that I wished.

What is the suitable event that I can use???
Is Mouse Down event suitable???

Comment: This heavily depends on what the items of your list view are. Objects? Strings? Other UI elements?

Comment: You could use `ListView.SelectionChanged` event.

Comment: @sthitakura indeed that would be the easiest option as .Net provides the heavy lifting. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx for references.

Comment: 'ListView.SelectionChanged' is definitely the right event if selection is what should trigger the action.

Comment: I solved with selection changed :)

Answer (score 1):

as sthotakura stated, you would use `ListView.SelectionChanged` event. Link to msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

example:

```
public class doSomething
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        ...
        // delegate event handler
        ListView.SelectionChanged += delegateEventHandler;

        // or Lambda Expression
        ListView.SelectionChanged += (sender, args) 
                                         => {
                                                // Apply Logic
                                            };
        ...
    }

    public void delegateEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // Apply Logic...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is suitable, then again GaussZ is correct. What about an user selecting this thing using his keyboard by tabbing and pressing enter or some other UI event?